# Ansible have shell command use stored password

Tags: ansible

Looking to have a way for a password in a file to be used when I call the shell script below. I don't want to have to type the password in for a lot of machines to copy one file over. I need to use SCP or ti won't work

I'm also using ansible vault

```
- hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: no

      tasks:

        - name: Copy File to Local Machine
          shell: "scp test@{{ item }}:/home/test/*.csv  /location/on/localhost"
          with_items: "{{groups['firewall']}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer provided below:

```
- name: Copy File to Local Machine
  shell: "sshpass -p {{ ansible_ssh_pass }} scp test@{{ item }}:/home/test/*.csv  /destination"
  with_items: "{{groups['firewall']}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the password first.

```
$ cat config.sh
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/default     # <- replace the ssh key with yours
```

Have it ready and run it before running ansible playbook

```
$ chmod +x config.sh
$ . config.sh
Agent pid 87414
Enter passphrase for /home/test/.ssh/default:
Identity added: /home/test/.ssh/default (/home/test/.ssh/default)
```

Then you shouldn't have password prompt issue.

Comment: is there a way to pull from ansible vault? i have the password stored in there

Comment: good idea, so why not try by yourself? I have given the way to go, you should be fine to adjust for your request.